# fuerte install rosmake -a fails

Tags: ros-fuerte, rosmake, osx, rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When i run the command:

```
rosmake -a
```

at the end of the install for fuerte on mac OS X, 2 files it tries to compile fail.
Can anyone suggest a way to fix these errors?

Output:

```
 rosmake -a
[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...                                                 
[ rosmake ] Building all packages                                               
...
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                   from /Users/******/ros/image_common/camera_calibration_parsers/src/parse.cpp:1:
  /opt/ros/fuerte/include/sensor_msgs/CameraInfo.h:115: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘array’ with no type
  /opt/ros/fuerte/include/sensor_msgs/CameraInfo.h:115: error: typedef name may not be a nested-name-specifier
  /opt/ros/fuerte/include/sensor_msgs/CameraInfo.h:115: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘<’ token
  /opt/ros/fuerte/include/sensor_msgs/CameraInfo.h:116: error: ‘_K_type’ does not name a type
  /opt/ros/fuerte/include/sensor_msgs/CameraInfo.h:118: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘array’ with no type
  /opt/ros/fuerte/include/sensor_msgs/CameraInfo.h:118: error: typedef name may not be a nested-name-specifier
  /opt/ros/fuerte/include/sensor_msgs/CameraInfo.h:118: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘<’ token
  /opt/ros/fuerte/include/sensor_msgs/CameraInfo.h:119: error: ‘_R_type’ does not name a type
  /opt/ros/fuerte/include/sensor_msgs/CameraInfo.h:121: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘array’ with no type
  /opt/ros/fuerte/include/sensor_msgs/CameraInfo.h:121: error: typedef name may not be a nested-name-specifier
  /opt/ros/fuerte/include/sensor_msgs/CameraInfo.h:121: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘<’ token
  /opt/ros/fuerte/include/sensor_msgs/CameraInfo.h:122: error: ‘_P_type’ does not name a type
  /opt/ros/fuerte/include/sensor_msgs/CameraInfo.h:138: error: field ‘__connection_header’ has incomplete type
  /opt/ros/fuerte/include/sensor_msgs/CameraInfo.h: In constructor ‘sensor_msgs::CameraInfo_<ContainerAllocator>::CameraInfo_()’:
  /opt/ros/fuerte/include/sensor_msgs/CameraInfo.h:67: error: class ‘sensor_msgs::CameraInfo_<ContainerAllocator>’ does not have any field named ‘K’
  /opt/ros/fuerte/include/sensor_msgs/CameraInfo.h:68: error: class ‘sensor_msgs::CameraInfo_<ContainerAllocator>’ does not have any field named ‘R’
  /opt/ros/fuerte/include/sensor_msgs/CameraInfo.h:69: error: class ‘sensor_msgs::CameraInfo_<ContainerAllocator>’ does not have any field named ‘P’
  /opt/ros/fuerte/include/sensor_msgs/CameraInfo.h:73: error: ‘K’ was not declared in this scope
  /opt/ros/fuerte/include/sensor_msgs/CameraInfo.h:75: error: ‘R’ was not declared in this scope
  /opt/ros/fuerte/include/sensor_msgs/CameraInfo.h:77: error: ‘P’ was not declared in this scope
  /opt/ros/fuerte/include/sensor_msgs/CameraInfo.h: In constructor ‘sensor_msgs::CameraInfo_<ContainerAllocator>::CameraInfo_(const ContainerAllocator&)’:
  /opt/ros/fuerte/include/sensor_msgs/CameraInfo.h:85: error: class ‘sensor_msgs::CameraInfo_<ContainerAllocator>’ does not have any field named ‘K’
  /opt/ros/fuerte/include/sensor_msgs/CameraInfo.h:86: error: class ‘sensor_msgs::CameraInfo_<ContainerAllocator>’ does not have any field named ‘R’
  /opt/ros/fuerte/include/sensor_msgs/CameraInfo.h:87: error: class ‘sensor_msgs::CameraInfo_<ContainerAllocator>’ does not have any field named ‘P’
  /opt/ros/fuerte/include/sensor_msgs/CameraInfo.h:91: error: ‘K’ was not declared in this scope
  /opt/ros/fuerte/include/sensor_msgs/CameraInfo.h:93: error: ‘R’ was not declared in this scope
  /opt/ros/fuerte/include/sensor_msgs/CameraInfo.h:95: error: ‘P’ was not declared in this scope
  /Users/******/ros/image_common/camera_calibration_parsers/src/parse.cpp: In function ‘bool camera_calibration_parsers::writeCalibration(const std::string&, const std::string&, const sensor_msgs::CameraInfo&)’:
  /Users/******/ros/image_common/camera_calibration_parsers/src/parse.cpp:12: error: ‘iends_with’ is not a member of ‘boost’
  /Users/******/ros/image_common/camera_calibration_parsers/src/parse.cpp:14: error: ‘iends_with’ is not a member of ‘boost’
  /Users/******/ros/image_common/camera_calibration_parsers/src/parse.cpp:14: error: ‘iends_with’ is not a member of ‘boost’
  /Users/******/ros/image_common/camera_calibration_parsers/src/parse.cpp: In function ‘bool camera_calibration_parsers::readCalibration(const std::string&, std::string&, sensor_msgs::CameraInfo&)’:
  /Users/******/ros/image_common/camera_calibration_parsers/src/parse.cpp:23: error: ‘iends_with’ is not a member of ‘boost’
  /Users/******/ros/image_common/camera_calibration_parsers/src/parse.cpp:25: error: ‘iends_with’ is not a member of ‘boost’
  /Users/******/ros/image_common/camera_calibration_parsers/src/parse.cpp:25: error: ‘iends_with’ is not a member of ‘boost’
  make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/camera_calibration_parsers.dir/src/parse.o] Error 1
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/camera_calibration_parsers.dir/all] Error 2
  make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package camera_calibration_parsers written to:
[ rosmake ]    /Users/******/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20121003-145938/camera_calibration_parsers/build_output.log
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< camera_calibration_parsers [FAIL] [ 14.72 seconds ]    
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package camera_calibration_parsers. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[ rosmake ] Last 40 lines_bridge: 4.0 sec ]          [ 1 Active 8/193 Complete ]
...
  [rosbuild] Cached build flags older than manifests; calling rospack to get flags
  Failed to invoke /opt/ros/fuerte/bin/rospack cflags-only-I;--deps-only cv_bridge
  Package opencv was not found in the pkg-config search path.
  Perhaps you should add the directory containing `opencv.pc'
  to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
  No package 'opencv' found
  
  
  CMake Error at /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:129 (message):
    
  
    Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package 'cv_bridge'.
    Look above for errors from rospack itself.  Aborting.  Please fix the
    broken dependency!
  
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:227 (rosbuild_invoke_rospack)
    CMakeLists.txt:12 (rosbuild_init)
  
  
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package cv_bridge written to:
[ rosmake ]    /Users/******/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20121003-145938/cv_bridge/build_output.log
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< cv_bridge [FAIL] [ 4.04 seconds ]                      
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package cv_bridge. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                            
[ rosmake ] Built 10 packages with 2 failures.                                  
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                         
[ rosmake ] /Users/******/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20121003-145938
```

Camera Calibration Parsers output:
http://pastebin.com/R4jakbTW

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45030/fuerte-install-rosmake--a-fails/) by [heyfred](https://answers.ros.org/users/1930/heyfred/) on ROS Answers with karma: 122 on 2012-10-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

cv_bridge is failing because it cannot find opencv: `brew install opencv`

I cannot tell what the problem with other one is, rosmake is hiding part of the error, please post the full build log for camera_calibration_parsers.

Also, I wouldn't recommend rosmake -a, you should instead build things as you need them, i.e. `rosmake <some stack or package that you want to use>`

---

Originally posted by [WilliamWoodall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3078/williamwoodall/) with karma: 1626 on 2012-10-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [heyfred](https://answers.ros.org/users/1930/heyfred/) on 2012-10-03**:
I have included a link to the log as it is quite a long file. Thank you for your help.